# Hiding the data in rows -Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have three rows.I want to hide the data in those rows and display those rows in different color.I tried searching but only found Entirerow.hidden,which hides the row number as well. Is it possible to only hide the data in the rows and display it using some other color?

Comment: The rows should be there,just the data should not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will change the background color to Yellow for rows 1 to 3.

```
Sub ChangeBackColorForSpecificRows()
    Rows("1:3").Interior.Color = 65535
End Sub
```

Change the Rows and Interior Color to suit your requirement.

**Edit:-**

> formupahidden set to true not working neither formatting it to locked
>   and hidden ,is hiding the content of formula bar – Sunaina

Copy the below code and do right click on sheet tab and select view code and paste it.

Close the VBA window (Alt+Q to close VBA window) and return to that sheet and check.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Rows("1:3")) Is Nothing Then
    If Application.DisplayFormulaBar Then Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Else
    If Not Application.DisplayFormulaBar Then Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Rows("1:3").NumberFormat = ";;;"` to hide the data.

Comment: Thankyou :) Though I tried jis but on clicking the cell it displays the number in formula bar.Also do you know what is the code for grey color?

Comment: The value of cell should not be displayed on clicking the cell.

Comment: We cant make the formula bar to display none when you want to retain the cell value.  Formula bar is the real indicator of what is there in the cell.  So hiding the formula bar may be considered with worksheet selection change event if needed.

Comment: @Sunaina - Are you **seriously** asking what the color code for grey is or is that a joke? There are thousands if not millions of shades of grey to choose from. Here's one `RGB(80, 80, 80)`.

Comment: formupahidden set to true not working neither formatting it to locked and hidden ,is hiding the content of formula bar

Comment: I updated my answer post so please check it to know how to turn off and turn on Formula Bar based on sheet selection change event.

Comment: In your code the entire bar disappears,I just wanted nothing to be displayed.It can be done by simply checking tha "hidden" for selected cells in the excel format cell option. Thanks a lot for your help anyway :)

Comment: Also there is another sheet1,if the value of a particular cell in that sheet1 is equal to a specified string only then these formatting should be done in my sheet2. I tried conditional formatting,but it is not possible it seems.Can someone help?